# java.util.function.Predicate#and and Groovy 2.2 closures

Tags: groovy, java-8, predicate

I have this Java 8 code which works fine:

```
//Java 8
@Test public void testPredicates(){
    Predicate<Integer> p1 =  (i) -> true;
    Predicate<Integer> p2 =  (i) -> true;
    Predicate<Integer> p3 =  p1.and(p2);
    List<Integer> is = new ArrayList<>();
    is.add(1);
    is.add(2);
    assertTrue(is.stream().allMatch(p1.and(p2)));
}
```

The closest I can get to it in Groovy (2.2) is this:

```
//Groovy 2.2
@Test
void test(){
    Predicate<Integer> p1 = { i -> true}
    Predicate<Integer> p2 = {i -> true}
    Predicate<Integer> p3 = p2.and(p1)
    List<Integer> is = new ArrayList<>()
    is.add(1)
    is.add(2)
    assert(is.stream().allMatch(p1.and(p2)))
}
```

The Groovy code fails with the following on the line which calls the `and` method:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean 
    cannot be cast to java.util.function.Predicate
```

If I replace the assertion with just `assert(is.stream().allMatch(p1))`, then the test completes successfully.  The problem is calling the `and` method on the predicate.

Inspecting for example `p2` in the debugger, I can see it has type `OneParameterTest$_test_closure2`.  Decompiling the bytecode verifys this.

I have a feeling, although I am not sure, that this relates to implicit closure coersion (see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+2.2+release+notes).

Is there any way to write Groovy code so that it creates the predicate as a true instance of `java.util.function.Predicate`?

Comment: Does the groovy version work if you write `allMatch(p3)`?

Comment: Two minor comments about your question: 1) You are not using `p3` ever, 2) In Java 8 you have `p1.and(p2)`, in Groovy you have `p2.and(p1)` in `p3`, note the reversed order.

Comment: good points, but none are the problem. calling "and" on the predicate is the problem.

Comment: Tried with Groovy 2.3 (which supports Java 8) and I get the same result.  Maybe post this to the groovy-user mailing list?

Comment: OK, I've posted it - let's see if I get any replies...

Comment: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/java-util-function-Predicate-and-and-Groovy-2-2-closures-td5719471.html

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to write Groovy code so that it creates the predicate
>   as a true instance of java.util.function.Predicate?

What you are doing there is creating a true instance of Predicate.  The problem is the way you are creating them is really only useful for single method interfaces.  Predicate defines several methods.  There are several ways you could go about this.  Maybe the simplest is to take advantage of Groovy's Map to interface support.  The code below only accounts for "and" and "test", but you can provide whatever you actually are calling and omit the others.

It is hard to say from your code snippet what you are really trying to accomplish but just to address the specific test you have written, you should be able to do something like this.  The test methods are all hardcoded to return true here, just like in your test, but you presumably would have real logic there.

```
Predicate<Integer> p1 = [test:{ t -> true},
                         and: { Predicate other -> [test: { t -> true}] as Predicate}] as Predicate

// in your example you are never calling p2.and(...), but
// it is included here for consistency with the one above...
Predicate<Integer> p2 = [test:{ t -> true},
                         and: { Predicate other -> [test: { t -> true}] as Predicate}] as Predicate

// it isn't clear why you are creating p3, but you can...
Predicate<Integer> p3 = p1.and(p2)
List<Integer> is = new ArrayList<>()
is.add(1)
is.add(2)
assert(is.stream().allMatch(p1.and(p2)))
```

Comment: I realize this example isn't really doing anything useful, but it does do what the test in the original post attempts to do.  Maybe you can figure it out from here, or if you can better describe the real problem I can show you a solution.  Anyway, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, the problem is that the earlier releases of Groovy 2.3 ignore the default methods defined in the interfaces.

From Groovy 2.3 [release notes](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+2.3+release+notes):

> Groovy 2.3 doesn’t support the new syntax constructs offered by Java 8
>   (such as lambdas, method references, default methods in interfaces,
>   etc), but you can very well already use the new APIs offered by JDK 8,
>   and even use Groovy closures in lieu of Java 8 lambdas.

It is fixed (at least for the above case) in 2.3.8 and 2.4 as part of [GROOVY-7104](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-7104)